# Can not run my GPU AMD card on my ubuntu 16.04, it causes the login looping problem

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, inspiron, amdgpu-pro

I tried to install the amdgpu-pro vulkan driver from amd support web >>> http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx  .
But it caused me the login looping problem, I aimed to solve the problem by uninistalling the amdgpu-pro driver using the Uninstall command in previous link, then rebooted, it worked ..
Now any recommendations to run my amd gpu driver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without this login problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running the amdgpu pro drivers.  After installing, I get a black screen ( monitor turns off).  Nomodeset leads to infinite logins, or using recovery.  I tried AMDGPU 17.50, 17.40, and 17.30 and get all sorts of weirdness.  I have rolling HWE enabled, and the drivers only work with kernel 4.10.0-28.  Any version 4.10.0-38, -40, -42 kernels all leads to a sleeping monitor on boot.  I’m running the RX 480.